# The 2 rep disappears a while after I edited a post and received it

Tags: support

Sometimes, for example during the night, I edit some post, and I get 2 reputation points. The day after, though, the +2 has disappeared. I check to see if I had a downvote or something, but the log shows nothing. Recently, it happened more than eight times to me. Is it because I should be the last editor of that post to get the score. Am I right?

Comment: When a post gets deleted, you also lose the +2 reputation you got from editing it. Make sure the "show removed posts" box is checked at the bottom of your reputation history, and those deletion events should show up for you.

Comment: yeah you are right. can you turn your comment to an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @NKN Again, they got nothing for it because they are >=2k rep.  Once you reach 2k rep, you get nothing for edits.

Comment: @NKN A slight wrong there, you should correct minor mistakes like that - that's what editing is for; formatting code correctly, fixing spelling/grammar/adding, removing tags/anything that makes the post better.  Just be sure to make it all in one edit. I recommend you check out the first bullet point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions for you about editing:

- first, make sure you get everything in a post. Typos and spelling mistakes are great, but there are other things you can clear up in the suggested edits of yours that I checked. Meta talk like "I don't know a lot about this" or "Thanks so much to anyone who helps me" should generally be removed while you're there.
- second, do not try to make answers correct (your objections to the edits on this meta question suggest to me that you think edits are for correctness.) Edits, especially suggested edits that have to be reviewed, are for style issues like spelling, grammar, word order, expanding abbreviations and numerals, capitalization, and so on.
- third, if a question is very bad think twice before investing your time in it. If it is deleted, whether by the asker or the community, you will lose the rep you gained.
- fourth, remember that users with over 2000 rep are considered to have learned the editing rules: their edits are not reviewed and they do not get rep for editing. If you don't like an edit, you can roll it back.

And finally, if you're going to participate in meta, you will have to take the good with the bad. Meta often doesn't agree with people who come here to say something isn't fair.

Comment: I agree totally but I think you forgot something: showing respect the thought and ideas of each other in such a website is necessary. If I made some mistake, I will accept to be edited and be corrected. but editors should respect the original question and do not change something unnecessary. It might hurt people.

Comment: you mentioned "If you don't like an edit, you can roll it back." and I did this. because of this I am getting 4 down votes.

Comment: I didn't say your rollback would necessarily be the last action, did I? But seriously, the people who edited your question were acting with respect and out of a desire to help (they no longer get rep, they are doing it **only** to help) and you will be happier when you know that. You may not feel capitalization or other minor changes were necessary, but they were not intended to upset or disrespect you.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but some might have done it for a lack of research (how suggested edit rep goes away is covered in the help and elsewhere), to show they disagree with your guess that the rep only goes to the last editor, or just because you got mad after your post was edited. People have their own reasons for how they vote, and Meta is not like the other sites.